# Enable footnote rule only for split footnotes

Tags: footnotes, rules, footmisc

I am using `\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}` to disable the horizontal rule separating my footnotes from the bodytext of my document.

However, I would like to keep this rule in the case that the top line of the footnote text is the continuation of a footnote that started on a previous page (for example, above the footnote text on page two of the following MWE).

Here's an MWE that produces a long footnote split across the first two pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}

%lipsum package to automatically generate placeholder text
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2-7]}
\lipsum[2-10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to add the option `splitrule` when loading the `footmisc` package:

```
\usepackage[norule,splitrule]{footmisc}
```